# How to add random number generated to previous location in array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

**Assignment description:**

You will write a JAVA program that will simulate a horse race with 10 horses. You must use an array. Horse 1 will be in position 1, horse 2 in position 2 and so on. All the horses will begin at location 0 (with a zero value in that position of the array).  The user will press <kbd>enter</kbd> for all the horses to advance. Every time <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed you will generate a random number between 1 and 3 for each of the ten horses, this will be the amount of spaces that the horse will "move" forward. That number will be added to the previous number that the horse had. The first horse to get to 15 will be the winner. Your program should stop after a horse wins. On each iteration you will display the location of each horse.

```
//WHEN THE USER HITS ENTER NUMBERS ARE ADDED TO PREVIOUSLY GENERATED NUMBERS
//FIRST HORSE TO FIFTEEN WINS
//IM LOST?? :(        
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Random;
   public class HorseRace{
      public static void main(String[ ] arg){
         final int ONE = 10;
         final int TWO = 10;
         int count = 0;
         int i = 0; //position
         String[ ] sWords = new String[ONE];
         String sONEWord="";
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Hit enter to begin race");
         sc.nextLine();
      Random ran = new Random( ); //generates random number
      int[ ] arrRan1 = new int[ONE]; //populating the array one number at the time
         for(int a = 0; a<arrRan1.length; a++){
         arrRan1[a] = ran.nextInt(3) + 1; //number from 1 to 3, then add 1
         }
         boolean exit = false;
      while(count < ONE){ for(int a = 0; a<arrRan1.length; a++){
            System.out.println("Horse "+ (i+1) + ": " + (arrRan1[a]));
            i = i +1;
            }


      System.out.print("Press Enter key to continue");
         sc.nextLine();
      Random ass = new Random( ); //generates random number
      for(int b = 0; b<arrRan1.length; b++){
         int a = 0;
         arrRan1[b] = ran.nextInt(3) + 1; //number from 1 to 3, then add 1
         }
         boolean exit2 = false;
      while(count < TWO){ for(int b = 0; b<arrRan1.length; b++){
            System.out.println("Horse "+ (count+1) + ": " + (arrRan1[b]));
            count = count +1;
            }
            }                               
       }
    }//main
  } //class
```

Comment: For this question to be acceptable, you must explain what problem you see in the code and what you expect it to do that it is doing wrong.

Comment: It seems that I am creating two seperate sets of integer arrays(1 string array) with 10 positions. I am unable to connect the dots. How do I add the numbers form the second int array to the values in the first?

Comment: example ...[5,7,9].=[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]

Comment: Using a loop. Hint: you don't actually need to create an array of generated numbers. Just loop on the first array, and in each iteration, generate a number and add it to that array item.

Comment: That what I figured. I have yet to see an example of this king of code online. THAT'S THE MISSING PIECE TO THIS PUZZLE. Once I get that figured out I just need to write a condition that exits when the value of one element hits 15...Nested Loop??

Comment: No. No nested loop. Just, after you add the number, you check the result to see if it is 15. But first, please understand that you should learn to write your code yourself, not copy it from online resources. Please use the material you learned in your course, and write your own loop.

Comment: You must be my professor!!...lol

Comment: No examples have been given AT ALL on how to do this (online course)

Answer (score 0):

here are the required steps

1. create empty array initialized with zeros
2. check if there is a winner
3. if ( No winner )

   ```
   - ask the user to press enter
   - for each horse add random number between 1 and 3
   - print the distance in ran by each horse
   ```
4. else

   ```
   - print the winner horse number
   ```

i provided you with the code , but try to implement it on your own

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
   public class HorseRace{

       // function that iterate over the distance array and check every element if the element is greater than 15 it will return 
       // its index , if there is no element greater than 15 , the function will return -1 
       // the function returns the first element greater than 15 
       public static int winnerExist(int [] distance)
       {
           for(int i = 0;i<distance.length;i++)
               if(distance[i] >= 15)
                   return i;
           return -1;
       }

      public static void main(String[ ] arg){
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          // distance array that will hold the distance ran by each horse 
          int [] distance = new int [10];
          // min and max are used to generate random number between 1 and 3 
         int min =1,max=3;
          Random randomNumber = new Random();         
          // winner variable will hold the number of the winner horse 
          int winner;
          // check if the winner value = -1 , which means that there is no winner 
          // if the winner value != -1 , this means that we have a winner horse
          while ((winner = winnerExist(distance) )==-1) {
              System.out.println("Press enter ..");
              // you can check for the string read from the user if it is an empty string or not ( not necessary ) 
              in.nextLine();
              // in this for loop we generate 10 random numbers to be added to each horse 
              for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                  distance[i]+=randomNumber.nextInt(max-min +1) +min;
              // print the distance of each horse
              for(int i =0 ;i <10;i++)
                  System.out.printf("Distance ran by Horse Number %d is %d \n" , i+1 ,distance[i]);

        }
          // print the winner horse number after adding ( 1 ) to the variable winner because horse number 1 exist in distance [0]
          System.out.printf("The winner horse is horse number %d\n" , (int)(winner+1));



       }

  } //class
```